# QtConcurrent::blockingMapped() and std::vector<> bug

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtconcurrent

It seems that QtConcurrent works fine with QT containers (`QList` and `QVector`), but fails with the STL containers, as opposed to what is claimed [in the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads-qtconcurrent.html)

Here are the dummy functions I want to use on my containers :

```
void addOne(int & i)
{
    ++i;
}

int addOneC(const int & i)
{
    return i+1;
}
```

Examples of what works :

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // Qt containers
    QList<int> l;
    l << 1 << 2 << 4 << 3;
    QList<int> l1 = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(l, addOneC);
    QtConcurrent::blockingMap(l1, addOne);

    // Standard containers
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(3);
    QtConcurrent::blockingMap(v, addOne);
}
```

What **does not** work :

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // Standard containers
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(3);
    vector<int> v1 = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(v, addOneC);
}
```

It cause a compilation error with atrociously long and obfuscate template errors.

If anyone knew why, it would really help! Thanks!

---

The error log :

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(442) : error C2825: '_Alloc': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
>   1>        .\main.cpp(187) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_real<_Alloc>' being compiled
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            _Alloc=int
>   1>        ]
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(442) : error C2903: 'rebind' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(442) : error C2039: 'rebind' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(442) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(442) : error C2039: 'other' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(442) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   1>.\main.cpp(187) : error C2248: 'std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_real<_Alloc>::~_Container_base_aux_alloc_real' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_real<_Alloc>'
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            _Alloc=int
>   1>        ]
>   1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(435) : see declaration of 'std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_real<_Alloc>::~_Container_base_aux_alloc_real'
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            _Alloc=int
>   1>        ]
>   1>.\main.cpp(187) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_real<_Alloc>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            _Alloc=int
>   1>        ]
>   1>        and
>   1>        [
>   1>            _Ty=int
>   1>        ]
>   1>        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Comment: Sotyy, I edited my post with : "It cause a compilation error with atrociously long and obfuscate template errors."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should explicitly give the type of the container to the `blockingMapped`.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(3);

    std::vector<int> v1 = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped<std::vector<int> >(v, addOneC);
}
```

Compile and give me the expected result in the simple example you gave.

Comment: How on Earth did you manage to figure that out? And how on Earth does the compiler manage to deduce the types in other use cases?

Comment: @UncleBens: Don't know ... when I looked at the `qtconcurentmap.h` file and see so many templated ways to use the `blockingMapped` function I though "perhaps we could 'help' the compiler" ... I ran into problems like this with my own templated container classes. It **must** have an actual difference between implementations (std vs Qt containers) on the Qt side, but I don't feel like digging into `QtConcurrent` code ;) ...

Comment: Thanks anyways for the help! I didn't browse the source as I was blinded by the fact that it worked for the Qt containers.